# How to get entire source code of FileSystemObject?

Tags: vba, vbscript

I am studying myself some Script Object with looking at reference from MSDN or googling. As skipped the whole properties, methods which object has, I can roughly imagine that how the object was constructed. But, If i can look at entire source code of each object such as FileSystemObject, I gonna much more understand the structure it has.

Is there someone who know how to get the entire source code of each Script's object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're a few decades off. Check out JavaScript or PowerShell. Even the latest version of Office supports scripting in JavaScript.

To directly answer your question, you can't. Microsoft only very very recently started making things open source.